# List index out of range in python writing the file to csv

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, csv

I'm writing the file to csv, but it says list index is out of range. Here is my code. I have a directory with 85 files.

```
import os
import os.path
import csv
import re
import calendar
path = 'C:\\Users\\akhilpriyatam.k\\Desktop\\xls'
text_files = [os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in os.listdir(path)]
for v in text_files:
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\akhilpriyatam.k\\Desktop\\xls')
with open('file1.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    thedatawriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    for v in text_files:
        months = list(calendar.month_name[1:])
        regex = re.compile('|'.join(months))
        iter = re.finditer(regex, v)
        if iter:
            idx = [i for i in iter][0].start()
            filename, timestamp = v[:idx],v[idx:-4]
            print filename, timestamp
            thedatawriter.writerow([filename,timestamp])
```

Here is the error.

```
IndexError                                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-0b1c3f1407ed> in <module>()
     15         iter = re.finditer(regex, v)
     16         if iter:
---> 17             idx = [i for i in iter][0].start()
     18             filename, timestamp = v[:idx],v[idx:-4]
     19             print filename, timestamp

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: always add in question **FULL** error message (Traceback) - there are many usefull inforamtions - ie. which line makes problem, etc.

Comment: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-0b1c3f1407ed> in <module>()
     15         iter = re.finditer(regex, v)
     16         if iter:
---> 17             idx = [i for i in iter][0].start()
     18             filename, timestamp = v[:idx],v[idx:-4]
     19             print filename, timestamp

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: add `Traceback` in question - it will be more readable and everyone will read it.

Answer (score 2):

[`finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) returns an *iterator* and it's *always truthy*:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: iter = re.finditer(r'[0-9]+', 'no digits here')

In [3]: bool(iter)
Out[3]: True
```

In other words, the `if iter:` check would always pass - even if there are no matches. And, when there are no matches, you are getting an `IndexError` while accessing the first element of an empty list here: `[i for i in iter][0]`.

Comment: I'm sorry but i have not quite understood how to make use of finditer() in my code.

Comment: @Akhil Kodicherla iterator should not be used as test condition, it will always return True.

Answer (score 1):

```
iter = re.finditer(regex, v)
        if iter:
```

Iterator should not be used as test condition, it will always return True.

You should change you code to:

```
iter = re.findall(regex, v)
            if iter:
```

`findall` will return a list which can be used as test condition.